# Extract XML file tag data to a text file(s) using Batch script (concatenation issue)

Tags: xml, batch-file, text, concatenation, extract

I have an application that will only output XML and my destination application can only read plain text files.  I have a requirement to split the `<pending>` and `<results>` tag data it into two files and concatenate the output to a single line.  I'm having trouble with that; any help would be appreciated.  Yes I would like to keep it in batch script.

Input XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<game>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <pending>
        <item>W1: Player 5 versus Player 28 • </item>
        <item>W1: Player 12 versus Player 21 • </item>
        <item>W1: Player 2 versus Player 31 • </item>
    </pending>
    <results>
        <item>W1: Player 13 defeats Player 20 (21-8) • </item>
        <item>W1: Player 29 defeats Player 4 (15-21) • </item>
        <item>W1: Player 24 defeats Player 9 (7-21) • </item>
    </results>
    <time>636680475521951568</time>
</game>
```

Required output(include the trailing space):

Pending.txt

```
W1: Player 5 versus Player 28 • W1: Player 12 versus Player 21 • W1: Player 2 versus Player 31 •
```

Results.txt

```
W1: Player 13 defeats Player 20 (21-8) • W1: Player 29 defeats Player 4 (15-21) • W1: Player 24 defeats Player 9 (7-21) •
```

The script I have:

```
@echo OFF

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"<item>" input.xml') do call :job "%%i"
goto :eof

:job

set line=%1

set line=%line:/=%
set line=%line:<=+%
set line=%line:>=+%
set line=%line:*+item+=%
set line=%line:+=&rem.%
echo.%line%>>output.txt

:eof
```

Output I'm getting(in a single file):

```
W1: Player 5 versus Player 28 • 
W1: Player 12 versus Player 21 • 
W1: Player 2 versus Player 31 • 
W1: Player 13 defeats Player 20 (21-8) • 
W1: Player 29 defeats Player 4 (15-21) • 
W1: Player 24 defeats Player 9 (7-21) •
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest instead of standard Windows batch files you consider using or utilising PowerShell for working with XML files.

Comment: Vbscript, Jscript and Powershell are all native to Windows and have methods to properly read and write XML files. Microsoft also published two utilities over the years that can read and export XML files to another format. LogParser and MSXSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm myself a novize in xml, but PowerShell makes it easy:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\25\SO_51509117.ps1
[xml]$xml=Get-Content .\input.xml -encoding utf8
($xml.game.pending.item|ForEach-Object{$_} ) -join '' |Set-Content .\pending.txt -Encoding utf8
($xml.game.results.item|ForEach-Object{$_} ) -join '' |Set-Content .\results.txt -Encoding utf8
```

Sample output

```
> gc .\pending.txt
W1: Player 5 versus Player 28 • W1: Player 12 versus Player 21 • W1: Player 2 versus Player 31 •

> gc .\results.txt
W1: Player 13 defeats Player 20 (21-8) • W1: Player 29 defeats Player 4 (15-21) • W1: Player 24 defeats Player 9 (7-21) •
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to brute force this with a batch file, this may work for you.

```
@echo off
set "results="
set "pending="    
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=<> " %%G IN (input.xml) do (
    IF /I "%%G"=="/pending" set "pending="
    IF DEFINED PENDING (
        FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=<" %%I IN ("%%H") DO call set "pline=%%pline%%%%I
    )
    IF /I "%%G"=="pending" set "pending=0"

    IF /I "%%G"=="/results" set "results="
    IF DEFINED RESULTS (
        FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=<" %%I IN ("%%H") DO call set "rline=%%rline%%%%I
    )
    IF /I "%%G"=="results" set "results=0"
)
echo %pline%
echo %rline%
pause
```